# Application ID and Package ID are different and it's crashing when a user is updating it

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I have been given a legacy application to update and add a new feature to it but after making the changes and uploading it to the Play Store I was notified that a few users are having crashes when the app launches.

I have had a look at the project and saw that when it was given to me it had a different application ID and package Identifier.

For instance the `applicationId` in `build.gradle` is:

`applicationId "com.project_name"`

But in the `AndroindManifest.xml` it as follows:

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.project_name">`

What can be done for the next update so that the users migrating to the new version don't face this issue?

The app works perfectly fine when the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app.

Comment: Nothing. You have different package names for the versions. Fresh install is their only option.

Comment: upload the new apk with old applicationId

Comment: @AjayChauhan The new apk was uploaded with the old applicationID, play store wouldn't accept any other than the original one

Comment: then how come you are able to change applicationId in the first place.

Comment: @AjayChauhan I have not changed the applicationID, I have made changes to the app. It's a legacy application which came with a different applicationID and package identifier

Comment: check application id in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

The package="some_name" you give in the AndroidManifest and the applicationId in build.gradle has nothing to do with each other. They can be different or the same doesn't matter and it certainly won't crash the application.

Check the crash log to know what the issue is and fix it.

PS: package value is where the Resources are generated(like R files) and applicationId is a universal unique identifier.